# os.rename() file to part of folder name

Tags: python, operating-system, rename

I have multiple folders that look like `folder.0` and `folder.1`.
Inside each folder there is one file (`'junk'`) that I want to copy and rename to the `.0` or `.1` part of the folder name in which it currently resides.
Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
inDirec = '/foobar'
outDirec = '/complete/foobar'


for root, dirs,files in os.walk(inDirec):
    for file in files:
        if file =='junk'
            d = os.path.split(root)[1]
            filename, iterator = os.path.splitext(d)  # folder no. captured
            os.rename(file, iterator+file) # change name to include folder no.
            fullpath = os.path.join(root,file)
            shutil.copy(fullpath,outDirec)
```

This returns:

```
os.rename(file,iterator+file)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I'm not even sure I should be using os.rename.  I just want to pull out `files == 'junk'` and copy them to one directory but they all have the exact same name.  So I really just need to rename them so they can exist in the same directory.  Any help?

#### Update

```
    for root, dirs,files in os.walk(inDirec):
    for file in files:
        if file =='junk'
            d = os.path.split(root)[1]
            filename, iterator = os.path.splitext(d)  # folder no. captured
            it = iterator[-1] # iterator began with a '.'
         
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(root,file),os.path.join(outDirec,it+file))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that your program is using the working directory at launch for your rename operation.  You need to provide full relative or absolute paths as arguments to os.rename().

Replace:

```
os.rename(file, iterator+file)
fullpath = os.path.join(root,file)
shutil.copy(fullpath,outDirec)
```

With (if you want to move):

```
os.rename(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.join(outDirec, iterator+file))
```

Or with (if you want to copy):

```
shutil.copy(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.join(outDirec, iterator+file))
```

NOTE: The destination directory should already exist or you will need code to create it.

Comment: thank-you.  The destination directory = `outDirec` which exists.  However when trying your latter line `shutil` I get `IOError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: `

Comment: @KennyC Is `complete` actually at the root (`/`) of your filesystem as your example suggests?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you.  `outDirec` is the complete file path to the directory in which I'm trying to copy files

Comment: Try printing out both paths immediately before doing the shutil.copy and verify that they are correct.

Comment: ok I figured out the file path issue but the `iterator` doesn't seem to attach to the file path.  I get this error:`shutil.Error:  'junk' and 'junk' are the same file`